# Sulfite drawing paper is different shades on each side

Tags: paper

[image]
**strong text**

I am trying to figure out why one side of the paper is different then the other.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts! Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. Your post only contains a picture of one side, so it's unknown to us what the other side actually looks like and what you expect it to be like. Please click on [edit] and add some more information or describe the actual problem you face when using the other side.

Comment: Sizing, finish (roughness).